# How can add JLabel on JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jdesktoppane

I want to add a JLable on my JDesktopePane..i wrote the below given code..but the Label is not displayed on the pane.

```
   {
      frame1.setContentPane(desktop);
      frame1.setSize(900,700);
      frame1.setVisible(true);
      desktop.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY );
      JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Main Page", SwingConstants.CENTER);
      label1.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD,54));
      desktop.add(label1);**
   }
```

Comment: why do you want to add the label (or anything else not being an internalFrame) directly to the pane?

Answer (score 5):

The `JDesktop` is one of the few containers that does not use a traditional layout manager.

In order for any component to be added to it, that component needs to have it's position and size set manually.

Try something like `label1.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), label1.getPreferredSize()))` before you add it

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel, add JLabel to it and then add JPanel to JDesktopPane

Comment: doesn't matter how deep the added hierarchy is - without explicit sizing/locating it will not show up in a layout-free container like JDesktopPane :-)